# How to keep the end 0 when multiply it by a number in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, integer

I have a program like this

```
   cin >> input;
   input *= x (a random number just dont care)
   cout << input;
```

So everyting works fine until the input number is 00 then it prints 0

How can you keep the other number 0 ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Print a "0" before the number? There is only one number "5", for example. There is no "05", or "005". C++ doesn't work this way. If you need to format a given number in some form or fashion, it is up to you to implement the necessary logic.

Comment: Use setw and setfill to get the desired format, as in: `std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << x;`

Comment: `00` is an octal literal, but no matter what representation you choose to display, the value is `0`. If you want to print some special representation then you need to do that

Comment: I don't understand what is the relevance of `*= x`. You don't get `00` printed before that multiplication, do you?

Comment: @ idclev 463035818 it did print 00 before the multiplication, at least in my code::block 
compiler

Comment: please include a [mcve]. What is the type of `input`?

Comment: This is a math problem 0 * x is always 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not understand your question... 0, 00, 000, are the same number but in C++ a number starting with 0 means that the base is octal and not decimal... indeed `int a = 08` won't compile. Also note the a number starting with `0x` means hexadecimal and since C++20 a number starting with `0b` is in binary.

If you want to print numbers with some kind of formatting, you have mainly two different ways: using streams and the C++20 format library.

## Streams

Are the "old" way to format the output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << setw(2) << setfill('0') << 0 << endl; // this will output 00
  cout << setw(2) << setfill('a') << 0 << endl; // this will output a0
  return 0;
}
```

- `setw`: set the field width
- `setfill`: set the character to fill the field

**`setw` is valid only for the next field while `setfill` is changing the stream permanently!**

For more information you can look https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip

## {fmt}

The C++20 introduced a python-like formatting api

```
#include <iostream>
#include <format>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << format("{0:2}") << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

For more information you can look https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formatter#Standard_format_specification